# Unity box to Mouse issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am having an issue with my code, i'm trying to move a 3D box to the variable of the position of the mouse, I need to know how to change the box's x,y,z with my mouse position script.
All im asking really, is how do I change my boxes x,y,z with a variable in another script. Thanks!

Code:

```js
#pragma strict

public var distance : float = 4.5;
var box = Transform;
private var firstObject : cube;

function Start () {
}

function Update () {
       CastRayToWorld();
}

function CastRayToWorld() {
       var ray : Ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);    
       var point : Vector3 = ray.origin + (ray.direction * distance);    
       Debug.Log( "World point " + point );
       firstObject = GameObject.Find("pos").GetComponent("cube").pos = point;
       firstObject.pos = point;
}
```

Comment: A transform's xyz within the scene is the `position` attribute, so `box.position = <...some var of type vector3...>` will change it's xyz position, i think in your example that'll be `point`, but it's a little confusing as to what you are trying to do with the `firstobject`, and not knowing what the `cube` script is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the other object is aware of your box gameObject (lets say under the name 'adjustable'), then its simply a case of:

```
adjustable.transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, z)
```

To make sure that the object is aware of the boxes gameObject, you could make adjustable a public variable, and then manual drag the box from your scene into the field that would be created in the component on the object in question.

Comment: How do I "Make sure that the other object is aware of your box gameObject"

Comment: Sorry, I was not very clear with my initial answer. I have edited the answer to provide more clarification, but I may still be assuming too much in terms of your knowledge. Let me know if that is the case and I shall try to clarify further.